# Is there any way to open a SharePoint Site / Page without letting Scripts run?

Tags: 2013

Well, this problem is resulting from a kinda funny fact: I've inserted with JavaScript an automatical "Tab-Close"-Script to close a SharePoint Site automatically. Now, after a while, I would like to change sth. on this page which closes directly. That's why I would like to know if there is any way to load a SharePoint Page without running scripts / without letting the scripts run.

Comment: Where have you inserted the script? In a webpart? If so, add `?contents=1` to the URL and close the webpart from there

Comment: You can post this actually as answer, cause it solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where have you inserted the script? In a webpart? If so, add `?contents=1` to the URL and close the webpart from there

Comment: Hereare all the URL 'tricks' from the good old SP2003 days: https://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/05/trick-the-sharepoint-query-string-url/

Answer (score 1):

Open the page in SharePoint Designer 2013 and comment out the script where you close the tab.

If SharePoint Designer isn't allowed in your organisation, download the page from the pages library and edit in Notepad or any other text editor. When your done, upload the page to the pages library again.

And for usability, closing a tab when browsing to it is really bad. It does not only confuse your users; they may think SharePoint is down or their computer malfunctioning. So please, don't implement such a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Benny. Is there also any solution without SharePoint Designer 2013? (Unfortunately in my company SharePoint Designer isnt allowed). Well, this site is just automatically opened after a Workflow :)

Comment: @SteffPoint Sure! Download the page from the pages library and edit in Notepad or any other text editor. When your done, upload the page to the pages library again. It works the same way :)